# Проверка regexp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Подскажите, в написании регулярки.
Нужно убрать любое количество нулей перед **первой единицей** *(единицу оставить)*  и убрать все 0 и 1 перед **а**. Latex выражение - **01^{01a}** 
Есть вот такой набросок https://regex101.com/r/yE5sJl/2  , но он убирает **{** и latex ломается.

Comment: нужно бы больше данных для проверки, у меня получилось так:  `^[0]+|[^^{]+[01]+`

Comment: Есть input  который  получает latex выражение - оно может быть 3х вариантов: **01^{a}** ,      **1^{01a}** ,     **01^{01a}** .
Нужно перед единицей (__первой__,  _ее оставить_) удалять все **0** ,  и перед  **a** , удалять 0 и 1 если они есть .

Comment: тогда так: `^[0]*|(?!1\^{)[01]*|(?!a})$`

Comment: для ваших примеров, если удалять то что вы написали, то всегда получится `1^{a}` зачем что-то удалять, если можно просто заменить на эту строку? либо пишите больше примеров

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
s.replace(/^0+|({)[01]+/g, '$1')
```

См. [демо выражения](https://regex101.com/r/OCsutU/1)

**Подробности**

- `^0+` - один и более нулей в начале строки
- `|` - или
- `({)` - Группа (подмаска) №1: символ `{`
- `[01]+` - 0 или 1, один и более повторов.

Совпадения заменяются значение первой группы, т.е. либо пустой строкой (при совпадении первой альтернативы) или символом `{` (таким образом, скобка не удаляется из строки).

JS-демо:

```js
var strs = ['01^{0001a}','01^{a}','1^{01a}','01^{01a}'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(/^0+|({)[01]+/g, '$1'));
}
```

Если очень-очень нужно, чтобы после `{01010` была `a`, добавьте блок просмотра вперёд:

```
/^0+|({)[01]+(?=a)/g
             ^^^^^
```

См. [ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/OCsutU/2).